# extract(raster,SpatialPoint,buffer). how to change row id's?

Tags: r, extract

I have two files:

- a RasterStack (with 2 layers, each represents a raster map) named m_stack;
- A SpatialPointsDataFrame (points) named shph (with columns populated with data);

i can extract a buffer for each point (bdata) for each layer by doing:

```
bdata<-extract(m_stack,shph,buffer=60, cellnumbers=T)
```

bdata returns a list, row id's of the list are set automatically.

my problem is here: i need row id's of bdata to be id's from shph (obtained from a column in shph file named shph@data$ID. Any suggestion how to do this?

Kind regards, Manuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list that is returned has no row numbers. It is a list! Neither do the matrices in the list have row numbers. To name the list elements you can do

```
names(bdata) <- shph$ID
```

Does that answer your question?